# Magento 1.9: Getting all products and a corresponding attribute using SQL queries

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

I want to get all simple products and in addition, I want to get an attribute called `title_name` for those products. The attribute_id (from `eav_attribute`) of the attribute is 450.

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE type_id = 'simple';
```

Now I need the join with the attribute and this is where I am struggling. How can I do that?

**Magento 1.9**

Answer (score 4):

You can use below MySQL query to get the required records from the database

```
SELECT 
    `e`.`sku` as SKU , `e`.`entity_id` as 'Entity ID', `attribute_table`.`attribute_id` as 'Attribute ID',  `attribute_table`.`value` as 'Value'
FROM
    `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
     INNER JOIN
    `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `attribute_table` ON (`attribute_table`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
WHERE
    `attribute_table`.`attribute_id` = 450 AND `e`.`type_id` = 'simple';
```

**Hope this helps!!!**

Comment: Yes, but there is no attribute_id column in catalog_product_entity? Did you mean attribute_table.attribute_id = 450?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: Excellent. I've been searching for this all morning. Thanks.

Additionally, if you're struggling with things like descriptions (in my case at least). change `catalog_product_entity_varchar` to `catalog_product_entity_text`